# Multiple tabs browsing?

Tags: browser

I like using many tabs when browsing. It's a bit annoying to click links and open them as a tab on Firefox. It's annoying to close and switch between them too (Next tab so I can read VS pull a list and click the next one).

I tried Firefox and the default web browser. I tried looking up Android Firefox for gestures or some way to handle tabs better but [it looks like I can't open tabs easily on it](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/using-tabs-firefox-android#w_firefox-for-android-tabbed-browsing).

Are there other recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Firefox wastes too much space (especially when showing open tabs), maybe they fix that someday. In the meantime, have you tried with [Chrome for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome)? It has [new gestures](http://chrome.blogspot.com/2013/10/search-by-image-and-new-chrome-for.html) to switch between tabs:

> In Chrome for Android, you’ll be able to:
>
> - Swipe horizontally across the top toolbar to quickly switch tabs.
> - Drag vertically down from the toolbar to enter into the tab switcher    view.
> - Drag down from the menu to open the menu and select the item you want    without having to lift your finger.

[image: Gestures in Chrome for Android]